# How to use ignite schema-import utility in unix env since there is no UI?

Tags: unix, ignite

In windows, I ignite schema-import utility to create the classes. How can I do the same in unix environment where there is no UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema-import utility was discontinued in favor of a similar capability supported by Ignite Web Console.

Give it a try because you don't need to run the console close to your cluster:
https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration

You can learn even more about this console's capability by watching a related webinars recording: https://www.gridgain.com/resources/webinars/apacher-ignitetm-web-console-automating-rdbms-integration